# codeigniter not fetching data from DB

Tags: codeigniter

Email or password is not fetching from db for verification.

model:

```
class Login_model extends CI_Model
{

    public function login_valid($email,$password)
    {
        $q = $this->db-> select('*')
                        ->where(['email'=>'$email','password'=>'$password'])
                        ->get('admin');  
    }
 }
```

controller:

```
class Adminlogin extends CI_controller
{

public function login_form()
{
    $this->load->view('common/login_form');
}

public function login_check()
{

$this->form_validation->set_rules('email','email','required|valid_email');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password','password','required|min_length[8]|max_length[15]');

    if ($this->form_validation->run())
    {

        $email   = $this->input->post('email');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');

        $this->load->model('Login_model');
        $admin_id = $this->Login_model->login_valid($email,$password);

        if($this->load->model('Login_model')){
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->session->set_userdata('Id',$admin_id);
        $this->load->view('admin/admin_dashboard');
        }
        else {
            echo "model not loaded";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('common/login_form');
    }
}
```

the above is my code.i am not sure where its oing wrong.My log in credentials are not getting fetched from the db?

Comment: pls always response to the answers by giving some comments or ,if it helps you, by marking it as green and upvoting, it is the best way to thanks all the programmers

Answer (score 0):

Your model should be like this :

```
public function login_valid($email,$password)
{
    $q = $this->db->get_where('admin',['email'=>$email,'password'=> $password]);
    if ($q->num_rows() > 0 )
    {
       /*here return only admin id change column name if it is not id*/
       return $q->row()->id;
    }  
}
```

In controller :

check for `$admin_id` not for model like in below code :

*Note : load your model in controller's `construct()` (just a suggestion);*

```
    if ($this->form_validation->run())
    {

        $email   = $this->input->post('email');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');

        $this->load->model('Login_model');
        $admin_id = $this->Login_model->login_valid($email,$password);

        if($admin_id){
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->session->set_userdata('Id',$admin_id);
        $this->load->view('admin/admin_dashboard');
        }
        else {
            echo "admin id not found";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('common/login_form');
    }
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#selecting-data